# How can I resize a layer now that I have paths in my image?

Tags: photoshop

I'm learning how to use Photoshop's pen tool. Now that I have a path in my PSD, I'm having trouble dealing with my unrelated layers. For example, I select a layer on the layer palette, then when I try to resize that layer by hitting CTRL+T, the path gets selected as the thing I want to resize. How do I ignore that path and resize the layer (thereby leaving the path unaffected)? The layer is completely unrelated to the path...

Comment: Off-Topic. You should ask this over at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I posted it here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/32149/how-can-i-resize-a-layer-now-that-i-have-paths-in-my-image

Answer (score 0):

Layer sizes are locked to the **canvas**' size, you should change the canvas size and every layer will change their size.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused. I've always been able to change the size of raster layers in the past without resizing the canvas (using Free Transform or CTRL + T). As soon as I added a path to my PSD, though, I can't do "Free Transform" on a layer... It automatically does a Free Transform on the path, not the layer. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that you were actually resizing the content of the layer, not the layer itself. As I said before the layer's size is fixed to that of the canvas size.

Comment: Ah. I see what you're saying! I guess my question then is how can I resize the content of a layer now? All it's letting me do is resize the path...

Comment: Because your path is the only content of the layer. What version of photoshop are you using? I'll check this once I'm back to my desktop.

Comment: I'm on the latest version: CS6. Here's exactly what I did: created a path. After that, I created a new layer and pasted a photo of a horse on that new layer. Now, when I try to resize the photo of the horse (CTRL+T), the path is automatically getting selected. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the path is not selected. Go to Paths palette, and deselect it.